# How to set resource file name to the text property of label?

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am working on aspx page. In which I want to call a resource file dynamically and set it to the label text property like this

```
Text="<%$ Resources:RESOURCEFILENAME, DatePeriod %>"
```

And this RESOURCEFILENAME is coming from the property to javascript variable 
like this

```
var hdnResourceFile = '<%= resourceFileName%>';
```

So, how can I pass the Resource File Name to the text property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('span[id$=yourlabelname]').text('<%= resourceFileName%>');
```

or

```
 $('span[id$=yourlabelname]').text(hdnResourceFile);
```